# How to get xml element with nested default namespace with XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<abc:root-example xmlns:abc="http://www.example.com/abc">
  <abc:test-object Name="DesiredObject">
    <root xmlns="http://www.example.com">
      <value>Hello world</value>
    </root>
  </abc:test-object>
</abc:root-example>
```

and the following java code

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(xmlFilePath.toFile());

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String s) {
        if (s.equals("abc")) {
            return "http://www.example.com/abc";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String s) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> getPrefixes(String s) {
        return null;
    }
});

XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//abc:test-object/root");
Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

The final node here always ends up being null. If I remove `xmlns="http://www.example.com"` from the `root` node, then the evaluation returns the expected node. It's unclear to me how I properly format the XPath request to get the node. I believe it has something to do with `root` using a different default namespace, but am having difficult figuring it out.

Comment: That is the FAQ of XPath 1, use a prefix to qualify the element name e.g.  `ex:root` in XPath and have your API (e.g. `getNamespaceURI`) return the URI `http://www.example.com` for that prefix `ex`.

Comment: So, in this case, is the XML sample that I posted poorly formed for using XPath?

Comment: I don't see it that way, the sample is fine, for the selection of the element in a default namespace it doesn't matter anyway what is outside, and for XPath 1 you need a prefix to select/qualify that element in XPath expressions, it's just that most people expect to be able to use `root` in XPath if the element has that local name, in XPath 2 and later you can do that by declaring a default element namespace but obviously you can have only one so with e.g. `<foo xmlns="http://example.com/"><bar xmlns="http://example.org/"/></foo>` your XPath needs to use a prefix or wildcard for one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the following:

1. In `getNamespaceURI(...)`, the value `null` is returned if the namespace prefix is not `abc`. But the default namespace's URI is `http://www.example.com` instead.
2. In the XPath query, no namespace prefix given for `root`. This is reasonable since it should use the default namespace, however it seems necessary to explicitly give an empty prefix now: `:root`.

Applying both changes will make the code return the node.

```
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String s) {
        if (s.equals("abc")) {
            return "http://www.example.com/abc";
        }
        return "http://www.example.com";
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String s) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> getPrefixes(String s) {
        return null;
    }
});

XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//abc:test-object/:root");
Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
System.out.println(node == null ? "null" : node);  // just to show
```

Output:

```
[root: null]
```

---

*Update:* As [Martin Honnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen) points out, although accepted by [`javax.xml.xpath`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html), `:root` is not a valid XPath expression. Also, `javax.xml.xpath` is only XPath 1.0 compliant. I've found another, rather verbose way to select the node with `//abc:test-object/*[local-name()=\"root\"]`, but it probably makes more sense to either just

- use namespace prefixes or
- use an XPath 2.0 compliant library

Comment: If some implementation swallows, fine, as long as you know that implementation, that but with the step `:root` in`//abc:test-object/:root` that expression is not even a syntactically correct XPath expression (https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-NameTest).